# "Evocative" vs. "provocative"

Tags: meaning, differences, adjectives

I am starting to use *evocative* and *provocative* interchangeably.  I would like to understand the difference between these words and when one should be used instead of the other.

although the definitions of these words are readily available, I am looking for an explanation for when one word should be used instead of the other.

Comment: One evokes; the other provokes.

Comment: That sounds like the difference between an internal and an external stimulation.   My initial though says that this difference is very subjective (this is probably at the root of my problem).  How do I get past this?

Comment: Cast your mind back to the time *before* you started treating these two words as interchangeable. If you can't remember why you used them in different contexts with different meanings, consult a dictionary to refresh your memory.

Comment: @tchrist said it. Nothing more to say.

Comment: Evocative is relatively new in my vocabulary.  I heard a preacher use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since my excessively heavy dictionary (American Heritage Dictionary, 4th Edition) is already out, I might as well see what it has to say on the subject.

> **evoke** *tr.v.* **evoked, evoking, evokes** 1. To summon or call forth: *actions that evoked our mistrust*. 2. To call to mind by naming, citing, or suggesting: *songs that evoke old memories.* 3. To create anew, especially by means of the imagination: *a novel that evokes the Depression in accurate detail.* [Latin *evocare*, to call.]
>
> **Synonyms** *evoke, educe, elicit* These verbs mean to draw forth or bring out something latent, hidden, or unexpected.

So, basically, *evoke* means to call to mind, to create internally. When an author *evokes* the wind, they create the feeling or image of the wind in the mind of the person reading the text. You can also evoke things by accident - a beautiful melody can evoke a memory of the time your mother taught you to play the piano, although the musician may not have intended to do so.

> **provoke** *tr.v* **-voked, -voking, -vokes** 1. To incite to anger or resentment. 2. To stir to action or feeling. 3. To give rise to; evoke: *provoke laughter.* 4. To bring about deliberately; induce: *provoke a fight.* [Middle English *provoken*, from Old French *provoquer,* from Latin *provocare,* to challenge.]
>
> **Synonyms** *provoke, incite, excite, stimulate, arouse, rouse, stir* These verbs mean to move a person to action or feeling or to summon something into being so by moving a person. *Provoke* often merely states the consequences produced: *"Let my presumption not provoke thy wrath"* (Shakespeare).

Note that in the definition of *provoke*, the word evoke is cited, but only in one of the four uses. These words *are* very similar. The main difference between them is the fact that *provoke* has lots of negative connotations attached to it. You generally won't see people provoking someone to hug other people, but instead to punch them in the face. It's related to the Latin root meaning *challenge*, which adequately describes the general antagonistic effect desired by the use of the word *provoke*.

As the other answers mentioned, provoking is generally a very physical thing. It involves words, actions, physical stimuli. Evoking, on the other hand, is generally very related to feelings, thoughts, and memories. It tends to be much more emotional.

Provoke is also distinct in that it requires an external provoker. You can *evoke* something within your mind all on your own - no external intent is required for the whistling of the wind through the trees to call to mind the time you stood on the moor and watched your house burn down as the howling wind brought the ashes to you.

However, external intent is required to *provoke* - you need a taunter for cruel words to drive you to punch them in the face. You have to have a provoker, and they have to intend to provoke you. (Alternately, you could just *assume* they mean to provoke you... the whale in Moby Dick didn't really intend to provoke Captain Ahab, he's just crazy enough to believe that it did. As long as intent is assumed, provoking can happen.)

You do not need an evoker to evoke emotions, and the evoker may not even intend to create emotion within the listener. A singer may desire to stir people to tears, but if an audience member is crying because the melody *evokes* the last song she sang before she lost her voice in a tragic accident, that is unrelated to the intent of the singer.

(All examples were created on the spot by the author.)

Answer (score 2):

'evocative' (adj.)--tending or serving to evoke (to bring to mind or recollection). e.g., 'this place evokes memories of happier years.' Provocative' (adj.)--serving or tending to provoke, excite or stimulate. e.g., a very attractive woman wearing a black, backless dress with deep decolletage I would find extremely provocative. But It wouldn't stir up past memories of other women in black, backless dresses with deep decolletages. I think the difference is 'evocative' stirs one's recollections and 'provocative' stirs one's sensory faculties.

Comment: Where are the definitions from? Always clearly format quotes as such, and always properly attribute them. Mods are instructed to delete unattributed content on sight.

Answer (score 1):

You can provoke thoughts and actions, but you generally evoke only thoughts/memories.